# How to Add Label to Simple Network Plot in R? Code Provided

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm loading in the florentine dataset using the code below and trying to visualise the network:

```
library("ergm")
data("florentine")
require(intergraph)
require(igraph)
marriages <- asIgraph(flomarriage)

# Calculate degree centrality
V(marriages)$degree <- degree(marriages)

# Plot
plot(marriages, 
     vertex.label.cex = .6, 
     vertex.label.color = 'blue')
```

Result:

[Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeWRb.png)

Question: the nodes have numbers, not the names of the families that exist in the data set (called `vertex.names`). How can I replace the node numbers with the names? E.g. is there a label function I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
# ?igraph.plotting
plot(marriages, vertex.label = V(marriages)$vertex.names)
```

The argument is documented on the page where you found the other arguments you used.